# Can't align-items in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not a good developer since I'm only a student. I'm trying to make a website for me but I can't align-items on my rows in bootstrap. I'm trying to do this:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bC2yl.png) but I'm stuck on this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row align-items-start">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="title">
        Lorem Ipsum —<br>Interactive Media<br>Designer
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col">
      <ul class="link">
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Work</li>
        <li>Experiments</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li>Instagram</li>
        <li>Behance</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-end">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="footer">
        All rights reserved© 1998—2019
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me?
The items just don't align like i want them to

Comment: what you want to do is probably related to flex grid layout. Check the documents out with some examples https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_flex.asp

Answer (score 2):

For this to work you need to put every element in single `row`. You have 3 rows.

Imagine row like this

---

---

---

Every line represent single row. If you put content in one `row` element it will be displayed in single line. If you put in more rows content will be displayed in more rows.

So your code should look like this

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row align-items-start">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="title">
        Lorem Ipsum —<br>Interactive Media<br>Designer
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <ul class="link">
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Work</li>
        <li>Experiments</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li>Instagram</li>
        <li>Behance</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="footer">
        All rights reserved© 1998—2019
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If this doesn't help then I didn't understood you correctly so come back here so we can fix it :)

**UPDATE**

Based on new info I got this should be new solution

```html
<div class="container-fluid top">
  <div class="row align-items-start">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="title">
        Lorem Ipsum —<br>Interactive Media<br>Designer
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid center">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col">
      <ul class="link">
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Work</li>
        <li>Experiments</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li>Instagram</li>
        <li>Behance</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid bottom">
  <div class="row align-items-end">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="footer">
        All rights reserved© 1998—2019
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.top {
  position: aboslute;
  top: 0;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: the thing is that I want to have my .title sticked to the top of my page, the .link at the center of the page and the .footer sticked to the bottom. So I guess I need to have the three .rows

Comment: I am glad. No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

align-items property depends on the height row. For this you can set height for row